# Linq-to-SQL datacontext not generating an object

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, namespaces, app-code

I am working in a .NET 2.0, recently upgraded to .NET 3.5 environment (VS2008, VB.NET) on an existing ASP.NET website project. I am able to generate a Linq-to-SQL Class (also called a DataContext?) in the App Code folder, drag over tables from an active connection, and save it. Let's call it MyDB. When I go to the code-behind file for my page and try to declare an object of "MyDBDataContext" it is not in the intellisense, indicating that it is not accessible.
I checked the references, and that has to be set correctly because I made the .dbml file.
I made a new test windows app project and it behaved exactly as expected, and I could follow [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) without a problem.

Is there something inherent to web projects that doesn't allow for these auto-generated objects to be usable? Is App Code the right place to declare it?

If you can't tell from the above, I am new to the industry and really new to LINQ.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try expanding the `dbml` file and open the `designer.cs` file underneath, and make sure the DataContext class is in the same namespace as the codebehind class. If not, either change the namespace or include it with a `using Namespace` statement the top.

Comment: great! thanks, that was it... just needed the basics re-explained.

Answer (score 1):

If it your dbml is in a folder inside of '/App_Code/' it may pick up the folder's name as a namespace. Eg: '/App_Code/DAL' would have the namespace 'DAL'. Give it a namespace in the designer or just use the namespace it is given, if this is the case.

Comment: this answer was a bit more thorough, and very helpful! thanks